# Using group_by in rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my array:

```
finalcount = Vote.where(:month => month, :year => year, :vote_id => vote.id).count
```

I'd like to use `group_by` (I think?) to group the votes by `user_id` (which each vote has), and then return the `user_id` with the highest votes.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried the `group` method?

```
finalcount = Vote.where(:month => month, :year => year, :vote_id => vote.id).group(:user_id).count
```

will give you a `Hash` where the keys are the `user_id` and the values are the `count`. You can then call `max` on this result to get a two-element array containing the `user_id` and the `count`.

Here's an example from an app I have handy, where I use the result of the calculation to find the correct model instance and read properties from it:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > ExternalPost.group(:service_id).count
 => {18=>1, 19=>1, 21=>4} 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > ExternalPost.group(:service_id).count.max
 => [21, 4]
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > Service.find(ExternalPost.group(:service_id).count.max.first).user.first
 => "Brandon"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really want is this:

```
Vote.select("votes.user_id, count(votes.id)").
  where(:month => month, :year => year, :id => vote.id).
  group("votes.user_id").
  order("count(votes.id) DESC").
  limit(1)
```

This will grab the user_id and count of votes they have, but only return the one with the most votes.

Why did your originall call have `:vote_id => vote.id`?  Does your Vote model really have a column named `vote_id` and is it different than it's normal `id`?

Answer (score 0):

If your table structure is like:

```
vote_id
user_id
...
```

This should return an array where the first element is the user_id with the most votes, the second element is the count of that user_id.

```
Vote.group(:user_id).count.max{|a, b| a.last <=> b.last}
```

Comment: If you don't need the other entries from Vote (aren't going to use them) then this is a very inefficient way to do it.  The best way would be to grab the single row from the database that contains the correct user_id and their count (see my answer).